# razor variable does not exist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

```
    @for(int i = 0; i < this.Model.PresetReports.Count; i++) {
        @{ var preset = this.Model.PresetReports.ElementAt(i); }
        <a href="#" class="@(i == 0 ? "selected" : string.Empty)">@preset.Label</a>
    }
```

It says that 'preset' does not exist in the current context. ??  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@for(int i = 0; i < this.Model.PresetReports.Count; i++) {
    var preset = this.Model.PresetReports.ElementAt(i);
    <a href="#" class="@preset.class">@preset.Label</a>
}
```

That does it.

Answer (score 6):

Try like this:

```
@for(int i = 0; i < this.Model.PresetReports.Count; i++) 
{
    var preset = this.Model.PresetReports.ElementAt(i);
    @<a href="#" class="@preset.class">@preset.Label</a>
}
```

but I really don't see why you wouldn't use a `foreach` loop which would make a little more sense in your scenario:

```
@foreach (var preset in Model.PresetReports)
{
    @<a href="#" class="@preset.class">@preset.Label</a>
}
```

Now this being said I have some doubts about `preset.class`. You really have a property called `class` (with lowercase `c` which is a reserved word in C#) on your view model?

Comment: I simplified it to keep it shorter. I was checking if i==0 then add class "selected" to the href. option 1 of your answer does not work, thanks for the response tho. ps. I edited my question to make more sense as to why I'm doing a for loop and not a simple foreach loop.